# issue with undefined var in javascript, jquery. how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, undefined

I am using Date.js to display some dates and a weird thing happens. If I use it in an array formed from within an `each` statement.

Here is what i mean:

If I pass and use the `events_array` to the `test` function array everything works fine, but if I use the `eventsArray` one, that should look the same, I get:

```
startDate is undefined
...new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate()).getTime()...

function getTest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/index",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            var eventsArray = new Array();

            jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {

                eventsArray.push(
                new Array({
                    startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
                    endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
                }));
            });

            var events_array = new Array({
                startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
                endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
            }, {
                startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
                endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
            });

          test(events_array);

        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What `test()` function?  I don't see that defined anywhere...

Comment: Why is `eventsArray` full of arrays with a single object in each one?  Did you actually mean to `push` just the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to fill `eventArray` with objects, not arrays with a single object in each one:

```
eventsArray.push({ // NOT new Array...
    startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
    endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10)
}); });
```

Comment: thanks all, this is the solution, in fact all answers work just fine, but seniority rocks :)

Answer (score 2):

Within your test function try following:

```
function test(eventsArray) {
  // try this

  eventsArray[0][0].startDate
}
```

`eventsArray` looks like following:

```
eventsArray = [ 
                 [
                     {
                          startDate: ..
                          endDate: ..
                     }
                 ] 
              ];
```

But you should make it easier:

```
var eventsArray = new Array();

    eventsArray.push({
     startDat: ..
     endDate: ..
    });
```

Don't use additional array within `eventsArray` if you not need it.

and to access that values use:

```
eventsArray[0].startDate;

eventsArra[0].endDate;
```

#### If you look at your `events_array`, you'll see that, you're not using additional array when you push data within it.

Answer (score 1):

your two arrays are not identicals :
            var eventsArray = new Array();

```
        jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {

            eventsArray.push(
            new Array({
                startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
                endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
            }));
        });
        /* here eventsArray is like that [[{
                startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
                endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
            }]] Look at the two [[ or ]] : array of object in an array
         */
        var events_array = new Array({
            startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
            endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
        }, {
            startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
            endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
        });
        /* here events_array is like that [{
                startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
                endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10),
            }, {}] only one [ ... array of objects ...
         */
```

i think you should use :

```
eventsArray.push({
    startDate: new Date(2011, 07, 20, 15, 50),
    endDate: new Date(2012, 00, 10)
}); });
```

Hope this helps